# How to hide breadcumbs on the front page?

Tags: theming

I would like to disable breadcrumbs on my home page and I don't know of any easy way to do this so I was going to just display:none the breadcrumbs class.

Suggestions welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using D7.  There are a number ways to achieve it. I am providing three methods here.

**Contributed module**. 
The easiest one is to use "[Disable Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/disable_breadcrumbs)" module.

**Theme Overide**. 
If you think it is overkill, don't want to use that module, you can also implement the preprocess html hook to remove breadcrumb like this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html()
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    // kill breadcrumb, set to empty array
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(array());
  }
}
```

**Custom Module.** You can also done this in your custom module by implementing hook_page_alter

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_page_alter(&$page) {
  if (in_array('front', $page['#theme_wrappers'])) {
    // kill breadcrumb, set to empty array
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(array());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You add a page-front.tpl.php to your theme (duplicating page.tpl.php) and than remove codes that prints breadcrumbrs.
Or, in page.tpl.php, add some "if conditions" to display breadcrumbs everywehre except homepage.

Comment: This is best method . (y)

Answer (score 3):

Well you can target front-page elements specifically by using the .front css class, which is added to the body by almost all Drupal themes. If you have the element in a block, you can also control its visibility by setting it visible to everything but the `<front>` token.

I'm sure there's a programmatic way to solve this question better, however, with this solution you won't have to delve in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The good way to do it:
themes/YOURTHEME/template.php

```
function YOURTHEME_breadcrumb($variables){
    if(drupal_is_front_page()){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used for fix the problem the hook_page_alter.

In my case, i hould disable breadcrumb for specific page according path

```
function mymodule_home_page_alter(&$page) {
  if(current_path() == "my_url_path"){
    drupal_set_breadcrumb(array());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually hide it with CSS.

```
.breadcrumb {
    display: none;
}
```

Works great for me.